# NLTK MEGAM Max Ent algorithms on Windows

Tags: classification, nltk

I have been playing with NLTK on Python but unable to use the MEGAM Max Ent algorithm due to the lack of a Windows 64-bit executable of any version of the MEGAM library equal or above 0.3 (needs to include the -nobias option for NLTK to work, which was introduced in v. 0.3).

http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/megam/

The author recommends compiling your own executable, although getting O'Caml to work on Win64 is just another nightmare.

Does anyone out there have a Windows compiled version of the MEGAM executable that is either version 0.4 or above? I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get Python NLTK MegaM library to work after a bit of work on Windows 7, the solution is fairly straightforward (in hindsight). My methodology is described below in detail and the links are included. I hope you find them useful.

**High level:**

1. Install OCaml Compiler (Special version: OCamlPro)
2. Download the Source Code for MagaM
3. Download and install GNU32Make utility
4. Edit the MegaM MakeFile in 2 places
5. Run Gnu32Make to Generate magam.exe file
6. Programmatically indicate the location of the megam.exe file to
   Python NLTK
7. Run the nltk.MaxentClassifier.train command

**Links:**

1. [MEGAM SITE:](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/megam/index.html)
2. [Windows OCamlPro Download](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocpwin-distrib/blob/master/Download.md)
3. [GNU32 Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

**The Gory Details**

There are some peculiarities of this process that can easily go south given the lack of documentation - I'd like to call attention to a few I found...

***Windows OCamPro***

It's very important to get the OCaml Pro version for Windows that's a self contained entity w/out dependencies to anything else. The version I have listed is just that, it'll install into a single dir of your choice. It is very important to add the path to the **bin** directory to the ***system path of windows***.

***MEGAM***

Windows is a challenge for this library because it's had some SNAFU's with the developer, so you are forced to download the source and compile it on your own. This isn't as difficult as it first appears. As a general process it's fairly straightforward to unarchive a .Targz file into a dir and unarchive it 2X to get to the source dir. The most important 2 goals to achieve is to (a) properly edit the ***Makefile*** and (b) ***add the path*** of the directory that contains the resulting megam.exe file ***to the windows system path***.

***GNU32Win***

This is a straight forward process, just make sure to **add the path** of the Gnu32Make exe file ***to your windows system path*** after install.

***MEGAM MakeFile***

In the directory where you unarchived the MagaM files, there will exist a MakeFile in which there are 2 line where you must get the editing right to ensure a proper build.

***First***: 
(swap out the bold flags in the commented out line with the one in the uncommented line)

- WITHSTR =str.cma -cclib **-lstr**
- WITHSTR =str.cma -cclib **-lcamlstr**

***Second:*** 
(Swap out the path of the first line with the equivalent path on your system)

***NOTE***: That path **must** point to the "\lib\caml" directory of your OcamlPro installation on your system.

- WITHCLIBS =-I /usr/lib/ocaml/3.09.2/caml
- WITHCLIBS =-I **E:\OCamlPro\OCPWin64\lib\caml**

**Run make in the megam dir**

At this stage, you should be able to just open a windows CMD shell, cd into the directory where you modified the makefile and just run make to compile and generate the executable file megam.exe.

You should see output similar to:

> **make** ocamldep *.mli *.ml > .depend ocamlc -g -custom  -o megam str.cma
>   -cclib -lcamlstr bigarray.cma -cclib -lbigarray unix.cma -cclib -lunix -I E:\OCamlPro\OCPWin64\lib\caml fastdot_c.c fastdot.cmo intHashtbl.cmo arry.cmo util.cmo data.cmo bitvec.cmo cg.cmo wsemlm.cmo
>   bfgs.cmo pa.cmo perceptron.cmo radapt.cmo kernelmap.cmo abffs.cmo
>   main.cmo

***Programatically Indicate the Location of the Megam.exe file to Pythons NLTK***

The last gotcha I ran into was how to precisely indicate to Pythonn NLTK the location of my magam.exe file. In the calling code, I placed the statement indicating such just before the line where I called the MaxentClassifier itself, and that worked just fine, see below.

Note: It took a LONG time on my development workstation so be patient.

```
 nltk.config_megam('E:\megam\megam.exe')
 self.classifier = nltk.MaxentClassifier.train(train_set, algorithm='megam', trace=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be compiled using cygwin:

1. download cygwin installer: https://cygwin.com/install.html
2. when installing, check gnu make and ocaml (both compiler and runtime)
3. change makefile

   - WITHSTR =str.cma -cclib -lstr -> WITHSTR =str.cma -cclib -lcamlstr
   - WITHCLIBS = path to your cygwin ocaml dir
4. compile using make. There might be difference compiling debug and opt build. I can build using cygwin with opt but not debug, and native with debug but not opt.
5. add cygwin bin to PATH
6. run megam with nltk.config_megam(your path to megam)

Answer (score 0):

The current latest ocaml compiler has failed to compile the old "megam_0.92" source code due to a major version upgrade, while the old compiler failed to install, and the new compiler reports errors showing that many functions are deprecated and missing many necessary header files such as stddeff.h.

You can search youtube for videos on how to compile megam on windows, but apparently these and those are based on older versions of the ocaml compiler and these steps do not achieve the goal within the currently available configuration environment.

Hopefully someone will share compiled binaries instead of just sharing instructions that don't take into account changes in the configuration environment and official updates that result in something that doesn't execute properly.

Comment: A word of advice:
If you are using Python and nltk on windows, you can use the iis classifier instead of megam, although running these on windows is much slower on linux, but it is always an alternative.