# Installing megam for NLTK on Windows

Tags: python, makefile, cygwin, nltk

I need to install megam for nltk classification routines in Python.
I followed the instruction by Milk Magic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606543/nltk-megam-max-ent-algorithms-on-windows):
0. Downloaded megam source from http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/megam/index.html
1. Installed cygwin with gcc, make and ocaml packages
2. changed the makefile
3. when trying to compile megam with a makefile I receive an error with the following content

> make
>   ocamldep *.mli *.ml > .depend
>   ocamlc -g -custom  -o megam str.cma -cclib -lcamlstr bigarray.cma -cclib -lbigarray unix.cma -cclib -lunix -I /lib/ocaml/caml fastdot_c.c fastdot.cmo intHashtbl.cmo arry.cmo util.cmo data.cmo bitvec.cmo cg.cmo wsemlm.cmo bfgs.cmo pa.cmo perceptron.cmo radapt.cmo kernelmap.cmo abffs.cmo main.cmo
>   sh: flexlink: command not found
>   File "fastdot_c.c", line 1:
>   Error: Error while building custom runtime system
>   make: *** [Makefile:101: megam] Error 2

Do you know what the problem might be?
Maybe somebody has solved the same problem recently and could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is

```
sh: flexlink: command not found
```

you need to find the package that contains it

```
$ cygcheck -p flexlink
Found 5 matches for flexlink
flexdll-0.34-1 - flexdll: Creates DLLs with runtime symbol resolution (installed binaries and support files)
flexdll-0.35-1 - flexdll: Creates DLLs with runtime symbol resolution (installed binaries and support files)
flexdll-0.35-2 - flexdll: Creates DLLs with runtime symbol resolution
...
```

So you need to install the flexdll package.

```
$ cygcheck -l flexdll |grep bin
/usr/bin/flexlink
```

Comment: Thanks!  
I've come to the same conclusion earlier, but cygwin installer didn't show me any "flexlink" packages, so I just installed everything from "develop" category and it worked.

Comment: Yep, cygcheck -c shows that packages "flex 2.6.4-1" and "flexdll 0.35-2" are installed.